# Default forecolor is set to ControlText and shows blue when running

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mdichild

I am wondering if anyone else experiences this. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, all of my form controls have a default ForeColor of the system ControlText.

The font shows up as black when in design mode. The problem is when I run my application, everything that has this ControlText color shows up as blue while the form is inside the MDI container.

If I make the form pop out of the MDI parent, then the font changes back to black.
Is this a glitch in my system?

I realize that the System colors sometimes change, depending on what colors the user selected for their computer system color scheme. But this font keeps showing as blue on win8 or winXP and doesn't matter what I change my system color schemes too.

Does anyone know what the deal is with this?
Is there a way to make my whole project quit using this ControlText as a default color?
Or is there a way to have my mdiParent control this color to not show as blue?

Comment: No, there's no system color that's specific to MDI child window text.  There's no simple explanation for this.

Comment: Hans, Is there some way of changing my default forecolor from ControlText to just normal Black so I don't have to keep changing it on every single form/control I create?  thanks for the help.

Comment: ForeColor is an ambient property, a control automatically "inherits" its Parent's color unless it specifically assigns a value.  So just setting the form's ForeColor to Black instead of ControlText is already enough.

Comment: @HansPassant i have a dark mode function on my app, this issue mad eme think i was crazy. Thanks